# How to zip an HList with a plain Scala collection?

Tags: scala, shapeless

How to zip an HList with, let's say, a Scala Stream to produce an HList of pairs? Specifically:

```
import shapeless._

val a = 1.3 :: true :: "z" :: HNil
val b = Stream.from(1)

val ab: (Double, Int) :: (Boolean, Int) :: (String, Int) :: HNil = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but there are restrictions. Mostly you have to specify the desired length of the Scala collection to be zipped. The result will, of course, be the length of the shorter of the two HLists.

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.traversable._  // toHList

val a = 1.3 :: true :: "z" :: HNil  // 3 elements

val short_b = Stream.from(1).take(2).toHList[Int::Int::HNil]
val long_b  = Stream.from(7).take(5).toHList[Int::Int::Int::Int::Int::HNil]
```

`toHList` returns an `Option[HList]` so we'll `map` over the results to extract the `HList` to be zipped.

```
short_b.map(a zip _)  // 2 element result
//res0: Option[(Double, Int) :: (Boolean, Int) :: HNil] =
// Some((1.3,1) :: (true,2) :: HNil)

long_b.map(a zip _)  // 3 element result
//res1: Option[(Double, Int) :: (Boolean, Int) :: (String, Int) :: HNil] =
// Some((1.3,7) :: (true,8) :: (z,9) :: HNil)
```

Comment: `toHList` is nifty (also solves the aforementioned safety issues) and since using `toHList` basically produces another `HList`, is there really no simpler way to `zip` two `HList`s of equal size? i.e. is there nothing in shapeless itself that would make the following compile and run correctly?  `Stream.from(1).take(3).toHList[Int::Int::Int::HNil].map(a zip _)`

Comment: You're right. `zip` is available and simpler. See the update.

Comment: ah yes, it does run. i was misled by IntelliJ complaining (incorrectly) about missing implicits...

Answer (score 1):

```
trait Zipper[A <: HList, B] {
  type Out <: HList
  def zip(a: A, bs: Stream[B]): Out
}

implicit def hnilZipper[B] = new Zipper[HNil, B] {
  type Out = HNil
  def zip(a: HNil, bs: Stream[B]): HNil = HNil
}

implicit def consZipper[Head, Tail <: HList, B](implicit z: Zipper[Tail, B]) = new Zipper[Head :: Tail, B] {
  type Out = (Head, B) :: z.Out
  def zip(a: Head :: Tail, bs: Stream[B]): Out = {
    (a.head, bs.head) :: z.zip(a.tail, bs.tail)
  }
}

def zip[A <: HList, B](a: A, b: Stream[B])(implicit z: Zipper[A, B]): z.Out = z.zip(a, b)
```

As Marth notes, there are safety issues and this will fail if the Stream is shorter than the HList. But you could pretty easily modify this to return an `Option[(A1, B) :: (A2, B) :: ...]` or a `(A1, Option[B]) :: (A2, Option[B]) :: ...` if that's a concern.